# The Iptables don´t allow update the system

Tags: iptables, raspbian

These rules don´t allow update the system (Debian wheezy on raspberry pi).
Don´t allow ping:
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted. I am trying to install a home web server and this rules don´t work properly. I want that the server allow my CMS (joomla) to update and allow the update of the system itself.
**What I need to change in this file to allow update joomla and debian?**

```
  *mangle
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [12:624]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [12:624]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:9440]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12:2128]
    COMMIT

    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    COMMIT

    *filter
    :INPUT DROP [0:0]
    :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
    :OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
    :spooflist - [0:0]
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 90 --hitcount 4 --name DEFAULT --rsource -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
    -A INPUT -j spooflist
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -f -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -m limit --limit 5/min --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-prefix " NULL Packets "
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -m limit --limit 5/min --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-prefix " XMAS Packets "
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -m limit --limit 5/min --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-prefix " Fin Packets Scan "
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j LOG --log-prefix " Broadcast "
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j LOG --log-prefix " Multicast "
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j DROP
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix " Invalid "
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.17/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    # ACEPTAR SALIDAS POR EL 80 Y POR EL 443
    #-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    #-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 30/sec -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-prefix " DEFAULT DROP "
    -A INPUT -j DROP
    -A FORWARD -j spooflist
    -A OUTPUT -j spooflist
    -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.17/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
    #-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    # ACEPTAR SALIDAS POR EL 80 Y POR EL 443
    #-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    #-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    COMMIT
```

The iptables -L -n output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 90 hit_count: 4 name: DEFAULT side: source
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source
spooflist  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags:! 0x17/0x02 state NEW
DROP       all  -f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x29
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x3F
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x00 limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " NULL Packets "
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x00
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x06/0x06
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x03/0x03 limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " XMAS Packets "
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x03/0x03
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x11/0x01 limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " Fin Packets Scan "
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x11/0x01
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x37
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = broadcast LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " Broadcast "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = broadcast
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = multicast LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " Multicast "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = multicast
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " Invalid "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.17         tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED limit: avg 30/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:123 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:25 state ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix " DEFAULT DROP "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
spooflist  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
spooflist  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.17         0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:20 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:123 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain spooflist (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: what is your system? don't you think it's a bit vague like this ?

Comment: `192.168.0.17/32` seems redundant.  Who wrote this stuff?

Comment: @goldilocks once in INPUT once in OUPUT no prb here non ?

Comment: It´s on debian wheezy on a raspberry pi. A friend wrote this by a script which found.:(

Comment: @djmanudj please [edit] your question instead of answering directly into comments. It will make the work of any personn trying to answer you way easier.

Comment: Without question mark it is difficult to see what you are asking? Are you describing how iptables works, should, failed to work? Edit you text so that the question is clear, use words like "Why" and "How can I"

Comment: "ping: ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted" isn't an iptables error. Are you sure this file is correct? It throws me "iptables-restore: line 1 failed
failed." What's the output of `sudo iptables -L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any rules that allow outgoing pings (ICMP echo-request - type 8). You only have a single rule that allows ICMP echo reply.

---

Additionally most of your `--state` matches are useless. With `--state NEW,ESTABLISHED` you might as well not use `--state` at all, as there's only 2 possible states, `NEW` and `ESTABLISHED`. Yes there is `RELATED` but related is also going to be new or established.

Also you can simplify this ruleset immensely by adding a single `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` at the top instead of having to do every single port individually.

Comment: You can also use `--dports/--sports` to specify multiple ports on one line.